# Copy/paste subsequent paragraphs from two Word documents one after another (to learn a foreign language)

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I have two books of the same title: one English, one Spanish.  I want to combine them so I can learn Spanish.  So I need a single Word document that has one paragraph in English, followed by the same paragraph in Spanish, over and over again.  Below is what I have from manually copy/pasting, but I would like to automate it using a patter of (a) copy/pasting by paragraph break, or (b) copy/pasting every 350 characters (or 100 words) with a punctuation being the end point.  This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Windows("3.doc  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=13, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Document2").Activate
    Windows("656398.docx  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=23, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=7, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Document2").Activate
    Windows("3.doc  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=8, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Document2").Activate
    Windows("656398.docx  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=18, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Document2").Activate
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
    ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: A good place to start is by recording a macro that does one paragraph and then the next. It will give you the base code to get started making an effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite «A good place to start is by recording a macro» The OP has done that and edited the post accordingly. Since the thread is still closed, though, no-one can provide an answer...

Comment: @macropod: I've voted to reopen. Thanks - I might not have seen the edit.

Comment: @braX: any chance of getting this thread opened?

Comment: Thanks everyone for getting the thread reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, provided the documents have exactly the same paragraphing:

```
Sub AddSecondLanguage()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocA As Document, DocB As Document, Rng As Range, i As Long
With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Select the source document containing the primary language."
  .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  If .Show = -1 Then
    Set DocA = Documents.Open(.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  Else
    MsgBox "No primary language file selected. Exiting.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
  End If
End With
With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Select the source document containing the secondary language."
  .InitialFileName = DocA.Path & "\"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  If .Show = -1 Then
    Set DocB = Documents.Open(.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=True)
  Else
    MsgBox "No secondary language file selected. Exiting.", vbExclamation
    DocA.Close SaveChanges:=False: Set DocA = Nothing: Exit Sub
  End If
End With
With DocB
  For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Rng = .Paragraphs(i).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Rng.FormattedText = DocA.Paragraphs(i).Range.FormattedText
  Next
    .SaveAs2 FileName:=Split(DocA.FullName, ".doc")(0) & "-Combined.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End With
DocA.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set DocA = Nothing: Set DocB = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The combined document will be saved in the docx format with the same name as the first document you open, with '-Combined' added to the filename.

Comment: Thank you!  I know it has been a while since I responded, but I greatly appreciate you helping to reopen my question and answering it with the beautiful code you put together.  Really great work :)